# Accessing MVC Action from another application via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have an MVC 3 web app that has an Action which I need to access from a webform app via javascript.

My action returns a Json result, which I have checked works just fine. However, when accessing it with javascript from another application, I can see it reaching my action, doing all the work, returning my data, but the jquery function then gives me an error 200 and no data.

Example:
My MVC Action:

```
public ActionResult GetData(int categoryId)
{
   var listofSeries = new List<string>
               {
                   "foo1",
                   "foo2",
                   "foo3"
               };
   return Json(listofSeries, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This returns me: `["foo1","foo2","foo3"]`

Normally, my javascript function is used to query a database and get data back for a Highcharts chart but I have the same issue with this kind of example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var foo = getData(9);
    });

    function getData(categoryId) {
            var results;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:xxxx/Home/GetData',
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
                async: false,
                data: { "categoryId": categoryId },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("results: " + data);
                    results = data;
                }
            });

            return results;
        }
</script>
```

With this I get:

```
http://localhost:63418/Home/GetData?categoryId=9 200 OK
results: null
```

If I add the contentType, I can't even see the function running in the firebug console, all I see is `results: null`. When I remove it I do but I get the error above.

I've been told it might not be doable because of "Cross-site scripting". And to instead have my javascript function call a webservice (or handler but I haven't quite figured out how to make one of those yet) that will then call my action, return my data to the service who then returns the data to the javascript.

But now I'm getting a 415 Unsupported Media Type error message when trying to connect to my webservice.

My IWebService.cs:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IWebService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
        void GetData(int mileId);
    }
```

My WebService.svc:

```
public void GetData(int categoryId)
{
    string url = "http://localhost:63418/Home/GetWoWData?categoryId=" + categoryId;
    WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse();
}
```

I'm not returning anything yet, it won't even go in this function. Giving me the 415 error message.

If I change the contentType to "text/xml" I get an error 400.

I would really like to have this work without using the webservice, and figure why I get an error 200 OK when I can see the action running, but if that's not possible, any idea why the webservice isn't working?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, I know I'm not using the categoryId in this example despite passing it as a parameter. But I do use it in the normal version of my app.

Comment: why is your function declared in your document ready?  probably not the problem, but doesn't seem like a great idea either.

your also missing a ; here: var foo = getData(9)

Comment: The ; missing was a mistake from typing it in here. I moved the function outside and the issue still occurs. I corrected the main post. Thanks.

Comment: is your controller action being hit?  if you put a breakpoint and debug, does it get to it?

Comment: With the Webservice no it doesn't. When I try from the javascript directly to the action, yes it gets hit, passes the parameter just fine and my action returns my results. The JS function then gives me error 200.

Comment: 200 is status code of Ok request. did u inspect your request in fiddler or firebug what response does it return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string url = "http://localhost:63418/Home/GetWoWData?categoryId=" + categoryId;
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; // uses current windows user
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
```

I only just remembered I had this post and found the solution a while ago. It was solved by adding the credentials (in my case the current windows user) and getting the response as an `HttpWebResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

200 makes me think everything is working ok, but IE is using a cached result, i've run into this problem before with IE.   try adding:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses */
    cache: false
});
```

this will make it append a random parameter, and will stop IE from being stupid.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running it all with Firefox. I added that anyway, but same problem. Error 200.

Comment: hmmm,  might still be worth a try.